# Entity Framework 6.2, getting runtime column missing using DB first

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbcontext

Recently the DB Admin added two columns to the database I use in my program,I need the columns as part of an export.

The DB already contains Consignee_Contact and the new Column added is Consingee_Contact2.

I refresh the DB form the Table using the Designer tool. The two new columns get added to columns in DB.

When I execute a data call for just the first row in Table, table in use an full of data, the program reports columns do not exist.

Is this because the first row does not have the columns filled?

Answer (score 0):

Well after much digging, I found the issue... The program was right.  In the program design there are 2 Databases potentially on Different SQL server farms + there is a different server farm for testing. So I could be looking at up to 8 different SQL servers. Right now both databases are on the same SQL server.

The SQL Connection string is stored in a config file. For got check this file. So in the file there are 4 connection strings, 2 for prod, 2 for test.

So on customer site the Severs for test are good and production are broken.  On my local test I used different SQL servers for each of the DBs and forgot to add the columns to one of the servers.

So I'm the broken one.  Thanks.